# HiveQL Where In Clause That Points to a Set of Files

Tags: sql, hadoop, hql, hive

I have a set of ~100 files each with 50k IDs in them.  I want to be able to make a query against Hive that has a Where In clause using the IDs from these files.  I could also do this directly from Groovy, but I'm thinking the code would be cleaner if I did all of the processing from Hive instead of referencing an external Set.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create an external table describing the format of your files, and set the location to the HDFS path of a directory containing the files.. i.e for tab delimited files

```
create external table my_ids(
  id bigint,
  other_col string
)
row format delimited fields terminated by "\t"
stored as textfile
location 'hdfs://mydfs/data/myids'
```

Now you can use Hive to access this data.